# Создание нового блока посередине сайта

Tags: html, css

Проблема заключается в том, что новый блок создаётся не в конце сайта, а в промежутках посередине сайта.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]. При надобности могу прикрепить код css файла.
Как вы думаете в чём проблема?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <title>пример</title>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=KoHo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1'/>
        <meta content='true' name='HandheldFriendly'/>
        <meta content='width' name='MobileOptimized'/>
        <meta content='yes' name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable'/>
        
    </head>
    
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <!-- Header -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="header-top">
                <nav class="nav">
                    <div class="nav_logo"></div>
                        <img src="images/Icon Design Company.png">
                    <ul class="nav-list">
                        <li><a href="#!" class="active">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!">Our Work</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!">Partners</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="nav-Contact"></div>
                        <button class="btn-1">Contact us</button>
                    
                    
                </nav>

                </div>
                <div class="header_row">
                    <div class="header_content">
                        <h2 class="header_title">Create <span class="colortext">the best</span> digital product with us</h2>
                        <div class="header_text">
                            <p>Whether it is to increase enquiries, generate more sales or<p>imporve your digital strategy, our passion is creating digital<p>excellence</p>
                        </div>
                        


                    </div>
                    <div class="header_img">
                        <img src="images/Image.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <section class="destination">
                <div class="container-left">
                  Because our patform has done a long reset with everal<br> other user and has done a reset with seniors so that<br>user can use our platform easily, and comfortably
                </div>
                <div class="container-right">
                   <strong><h2>Why should you choose our platform and use it every day?</h2></strong>  
                </div>
            </section>  
            <section class="destination2">
                <div class="container-top">
                    <div class="left_part_beadg">
                    <a>OUR WORK</a>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="left_part_1">
                    <h1>We are on a mission to<br> help businesses grow<br> faster than ever</h1>
                </div>
                    <div class="right_part">
                        <img src="images/rocket.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="right_part_stars">
                        <img src="images/stars.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="right_part_trophy">
                        <img src="images/trophy.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="right_part_text">
                        <a>Marketing strategy simplifield. DesignCompany is a one-stop shop that provides your company with a skilled marketing staff, expertise, and resources for endless development.</ф>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="container_row">
                    <div class="box1">
                        <div class="img_card">
                            <div class="head_text_box1">
                                <p>95%</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="low_text_box1">
                                <p>ROAS has increased in comparison to prior findings</p>
                            </div>
                            <img src="images/名片_id-card 1.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box2">
                        <div class="head_text_box2">
                            <p>350%</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="low_text_box2">
                            <p>Average annual growth rate among our clientele</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="img_tree">
                            <img src="images/松树_christmas-tree-one 1.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box3">
                        <div class="head_text_box3">
                            <p>25$+</p>
                            <div class="low_text_box3">
                                <p>Revenue that can be tracked across our portfolio</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="img_money">
                            <img src="images/Money Icon.png">
                        
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                
            </section>
            <section class="service_container">
                <div class="right_sec">
                    <div class="right_sec_head">
                        <P>Core values we always live by</P>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right_sec_photo">
                        <img src="images/Image pallete.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="left_sec">
                    <div class="left_sec_1">
                        <div class="left_sec_1_head_text">
                            <p>Pixel Perfection</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="left_sec_1_other_text">
                            <p>With high dedication, our designs are always perfectly to the applied container which also pixel</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="left_sec_1_photo">
                            <img src="images/pixel icon.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="left_sec_2">
                        <div class="left_sec_2_head_text">
                            <p>Consistent Deadline</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="left_sec_2_other_text">
                            <p>We always update our design by daily basis. It is better if we know what is the problem faster</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="left_sec_2_photo">
                            <img src="images/calendar icon.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="left_sec_3">
                        <div class="left_sec_3_head_text">
                            <p>Updated style</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="left_sec_3_other_text">
                            <p>With highly - competent designers will always update about the most recent design style</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="left_sec_3_photo">
                            <img src="images/target icon.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="left_sec_4">
                        <div class="left_sec_4_head_text">
                            <p>Transparency</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="left_sec_4_other_text">
                            <p>Keeping the relationship between us and client as clear as possible to achieve client is goals</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="left_sec_4_photo">
                            <img src="images/eyes icon.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="partners">
                <div class="partners_head_text">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="partners_bottom_text">

                </div>
                <div class="partners_logo">

                </div>
                <div class="partners_picture">

                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        


    </body>
</html>
```

css

```
.header-top{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items:center;
    width: 1410px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-bottom: 187px;
    padding-top: 22px;
    
}

.nav{
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    column-gap: 40px;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1410px;
    height: 40px;
    left: 255px;
    top: 22px;

    
}
.nav-Contact{
    display: flex;
    font-family: 'KoHo';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 23px;
    letter-spacing: -0.01em;

    color: #263238;
}
.nav_logo{
    padding: 13px; 
}


.nav-list{

    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    column-gap: 40px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 22px;
    padding-left: 370px;
    font-family: 'KoHo';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 23px;
    letter-spacing: -0.01em;
}
.nav-list a.active{
    position: relative;
}

.nav-list a.active::after,
.nav-list a:hover::after{
    content: "";
    background-color: #EBB762;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: relative;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: -6px;
    display: block;
    /* width: 10px; */
    height: 5px;
    left: 0px;
}

:root{
    --container-width:1440px;
    --container-padding:15px;
}

.container{
    max-width: var(--container-width);
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0 var(--container-padding);
}

.header_row{
    display: flex;
}
.header-content{
    max-width:480px;
}
.header_img img{
    
    position: absolute;
    width: 533.01px;
    height: 518.92px;
    left: 1114px;
    top: 185.5px;


}

.header{
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(235, 183, 98, 0.226);
    width: 1911px;
    height: 809px;
    align-items: center;
    background-size: cover;
    right: 312px;
    
}
.body{
    font-family: 'KoHo', sans-serif;
}
.nav a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #000 !important;
    
      
  }

  /* button */

.btn-1{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:7px 16px;
    background-color: rgba(235, 183, 98, 0.8);
    border-radius:5px 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    border:none;
    width: 125px;
    height: 40px;
    left: 1400px;
    
    
  }
.btn-1:hover{
    border: solid;
    transition: border 0.1s ease-in;
}
/* header content */
.header_title{
    position: absolute;
    width: 480px;
    height: 264px;
    left: 270px;
    top: 233.5px;

    font-family: 'KoHo';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 66px;
    line-height: 88px;
    /* or 133% */

    letter-spacing: 0.03em;

    color: #263238;

    text-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.header_text{
    
position: absolute;
width: 480px;
height: 90px;
left: 270px;
top: 536.5px;


font-family: 'KoHo';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 167%;
/* or 167% */

letter-spacing: -0.01em;

color: #425358;
}
.colortext{
    color: #EBB762;
}

/* destination */
.destination{
    display:flex;
    justify-items: center;

    
}

.container-left{
    position: absolute;
    width: 468.67px;
    height: 88px;
    left: 257px;
    top: 1112px;

    font-family: 'KoHo';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /* or 167% */

    letter-spacing: 0.03em;

    color: #263238;
    

    box-sizing: border-box;

    position: absolute;
    width: 1409px;
    height: 398px;
    left: 256px;
    top: 965px;

    background: #FAFAFA;
    border-width: 1.5px 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #EBB762;

    padding-top: 147px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right:95.33px;
    padding-bottom:110px;
    
    
}
.container-right{
    position: absolute;
    width: 530.41px;
    height: 176px;
    left: 914.69px;
    top: 1077px;

    font-family: 'KoHo';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 88px;
    /* or 183% */

    letter-spacing: 0.03em;

    color: #263238;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    position: absolute;
    width: 823.61px;
    height: 396px;
    left: 821px;
    top: 967px;
    

    border-left: 1.5px solid #EBB762;

    padding-top: 112px;
    padding-left:93.69px;
    padding-right:199.52px;
    padding-bottom:110px;
}

.destination2{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1410px;
    height: 817.37px;
    left: 255px;
    top: 1544.63px;
    background-color: #fff;

}
.left_part_beadg{
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    left: 5px;
    top: 1px;

    font-family: 'KoHo';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /* identical to box height, or 167% */

    letter-spacing: 0.03em;

    color: #263238;


    padding: 6px;

}
.left_part_1{
    
    position: absolute;
    width: 508px;
    height: 259px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 210px;

    font-family: 'KoHo';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 78px;
    line-height: 100px;
    /* or 183% */

    letter-spacing: 0.03em;

    color: #263238;

    }

.right_part{
    position: absolute;
    left: 38.13%;
    right: 7.81%;
    top: 33.01%;
    bottom: 62.72%;

    transform: matrix(0.99, 0.14, -0.16, 0.99, 0, 0);
}

.right_part_stars{
    position: absolute;
    left: 45.92%;
    right: 37.36%;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 65.11%;

    transform: matrix(0.94, 0.31, -0.36, 0.95, 0, 0);
}

.right_part_trophy{
    position: absolute;
    width: 48.35px;
    height: 86.31px;
    left: 960px;
    top: 0px;
    

    transform: rotate(19.52deg);
}

.right_part_text{
    position: absolute;
    width: 437px;
    height: 123px;
    left: 970px;
    top: 330px;

    font-family: 'KoHo';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /* or 167% */

    letter-spacing: 0.03em;

    color: #263238;
}
.container_row{
    display: block;
    justify-content:space-between;
}

.box1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 450px;
    height: 330px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 487px;

    background: #F7E2C0;
    border: 1px solid #EBB762;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.box2{
    position: absolute;
    width: 450px;
    height: 330px;
    left: 480px;
    top: 487px;
    
    background: #F7E2C0;
    border: 1px solid #EBB762;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.box3{
    position: absolute;
    width: 450px;
    height: 330px;
    left: 960px;
    top: 487px;
    
    background: #F7E2C0;
    border: 1px solid #EBB762;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.img_card{
    position: absolute;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    left: 34px;
    top: 19px;
}
.img_tree{
    position: absolute;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    left: 34px;
    top: 19px;
    
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
}
.img_money{
    position: absolute;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    left: 34px;
    top: 19px;
}

.head_text_box1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 280px;
    height: 60px;
    left: 1px;
    top: 116px;
    
    font-family: 'KoHo';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 96px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /* or 31% */
    
    letter-spacing: 0.03em;
    
    color: #263238;
    
}
.head_text_box2{
    position: absolute;
    width: 280px;
    height: 60px;
    left: 34px;
    top: 126px;

    font-family: 'KoHo';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 96px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /* or 31% */

    letter-spacing: 0.03em;

    color: #263238;

}
.head_text_box3{
    position: absolute;
    width: 258px;
    height: 60px;
    left: 34px;
    top: 129px;

    font-family: 'KoHo';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 96px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /* or 31% */

    letter-spacing: 0.03em;

color: #263238;
}

.low_text_box1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 299px;
    height: 57px;
    left: 3px;
    top: 210px;
    
    font-family: 'KoHo';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /* or 167% */
    
    letter-spacing: 0.03em;
    
    color: #263238;
}
.low_text_box2{
    position: absolute;
    width: 299px;
    height: 57px;
    left: 38px;
    top: 227px;
    
    font-family: 'KoHo';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /* or 167% */
    
    letter-spacing: 0.03em;
    
    color: #263238;
}
.low_text_box3{
    position: absolute;
    width: 299px;
    height: 57px;
    left: 4px;
    top: 99px;
    
    font-family: 'KoHo';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /* or 167% */
    
    letter-spacing: 0.03em;
    
    color: #263238;
}

.service_container{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1407px;
    height: 638px;
    left: 256px;
    top: 2643px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.right_sec_head{
    position: absolute;
    width: 563px;
    height: 173px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;

    font-family: 'KoHo';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 64px;
    line-height: 88px;
    /* or 138% */

    letter-spacing: 0.03em;

    color: #263238;

    text-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    }

.right_sec_photo{
    position: absolute;
    width: 569px;
    height: 383px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 255px;

    
}

.left_sec_1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 226px;
    height: 256px;
    
    
}
.left_sec_2{
    position: absolute;
    width: 236px;
    height: 256px;
}
.left_sec_3{
    position: absolute;
    width: 226px;
    height: 256px;
    
}
.left_sec_4{
    position: absolute;
    width: 226px;
    height: 256px;
}


.left_sec_1_photo{
    position: absolute;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    left: 900px;
    top: 20px;
}
.left_sec_2_photo{
    position: absolute;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    left: 1170px;
    top: 20px;
}
.left_sec_3_photo{
    position: absolute;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    left: 900px;
    top: 370px;
}
.left_sec_4_photo{
    position: absolute;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    left: 1170px;
    top: 370px;
}

.left_sec_1_head_text{
/* Pixel Perfection */


    position: absolute;
    width: 199px;
    height: 25px;
    left: 900px;
    top: 90px;

    font-family: 'KoHo';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /* or 125% */

    letter-spacing: 0.03em;

    color: #263238;
}
.left_sec_2_head_text{
    position: absolute;
    width: 236px;
    height: 25px;
    left: 1170px;
    top: 90px;
    
    font-family: 'KoHo';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /* or 125% */
    
    letter-spacing: 0.03em;
    
    color: #263238;
}
.left_sec_3_head_text{
    position: absolute;
    width: 199px;
    height: 25px;
    left: 900px;
    top: 440px;

    font-family: 'KoHo';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /* or 125% */

    letter-spacing: 0.03em;

    color: #263238;
}
.left_sec_4_head_text{
    position: absolute;
    width: 199px;
    height: 25px;
    left: 1170px;
    top: 440px;
    
    font-family: 'KoHo';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /* or 125% */
    
    letter-spacing: 0.03em;
    
    color: #263238;
}

.left_sec_1_other_text{
    position: absolute;
    width: 226px;
    height: 116px;
    left: 900px;
    top: 140px;

    font-family: 'KoHo';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /* or 188% */

    letter-spacing: 0.03em;

    color: #263238;
    }
.left_sec_2_other_text{
    position: absolute;
    width: 226px;
    height: 116px;
    left: 1170px;
    top: 140px;

    font-family: 'KoHo';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /* or 188% */

    letter-spacing: 0.03em;

    color: #263238;
}
.left_sec_3_other_text{
    position: absolute;
    width: 226px;
    height: 116px;
    left: 900px;
    top: 488px;

    font-family: 'KoHo';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /* or 188% */

    letter-spacing: 0.03em;

    color: #263238;
}
.left_sec_4_other_text{
    position: absolute;
    width: 226px;
    height: 116px;
    left: 1170px;
    top: 488px;
    
    font-family: 'KoHo';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /* or 188% */
    
    letter-spacing: 0.03em;
    
    color: #263238; 
}
.partners{
    width: 1088px;
    height: 988px;
    background-color:#F7E2C0;
}
```

Comment: Как минимум потому, что у вас некорректно закрыт тег в строчке `<a>Marketing strategy simplifield. DesignCompany is a one-stop shop that provides your company with a skilled marketing staff, expertise, and resources for endless development.</ф>`

Comment: я исправил, но проблема не в этом

Comment: Приложите стили тогда

Comment: стили приложил.

Comment: Ваша проблема в том, что вы на все секции навесили `position:absolute` (очень странное решение, на мой взгляд), кроме последней. При абсолютном позиционировании блоки теряют эффект коллизии, поэтому секция с классом `partners` находится после после последнего элемента, не обладающего данным свойством. Решения два: добавить `position: absolute` последней секции и выровнять через `top', 'left', 'right', 'bottom`; либо убрать абсолютное позиционирование у всех блоков (на мой взгляд, более верный вариант)